# jQuery plugin: maintaining options across objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am butchering a very standard "Drag and Resize" jQuery plugin from [Brice Burgess](http://jquery.iceburg.net/jqDnR/). I have tried adapting it by passing an optional "keep ratio" parameter to constrain the width and height when resizing. This works great, but if I try to run the plugin on two different elements then both of them will use the options of the last one. Can somebody help me understand how to make sure that each instance has it's own separate options?

```
(function($) {
var ratio, minx;

$.fn.jqDrag = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        div: ".jqDrag"
    }, options);

    return i(this, settings.div, 'drag');
};

$.fn.jqResize = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        minx: 15, // we don't have miny as it would not work when we want to keep proportions
        div: ".jqResize",
        keepRatio: false
    }, options);

    ratio = settings.keepRatio;
    minx = settings.minx;

    return i(this, settings.div, 'resize');
};

$.jqDnR = {
    dnr: {},
    e: 0,
    drag: function(v) {
        if (M.k == 'drag')
        {
            E.css({
               left: M.X + v.pageX - M.pX,
               top: M.Y + v.pageY - M.pY
           });
        }
        else {
            var width = Math.max(v.pageX - M.pX + M.W, 0);
            width = (width < minx) ? minx : width;
            var height = Math.max(v.pageY - M.pY + M.H, 0);
            height = (ratio == true) ? width / (E.width() / E.height()) : height;
            E.css({width: width, height: height});
        }

        // stupid ie dropping the filter when dragging
        try {
            document.getElementById(E.attr('id')).style.removeAttribute('filter');
        }
        catch (e) {}

        return (false);
    },
    stop: function() {
        E.css('opacity', M.o);
        // stupid ie dropping the filter when dragging
        $(document).unbind('mousemove', J.drag).unbind('mouseup', J.stop);
        try {
            document.getElementById(E.attr('id')).style.removeAttribute('filter');
        }
        catch (e) {}
    }
};
var J = $.jqDnR,
M = J.dnr,
E = J.e,
i = function(e, h, k) {
    return e.each(function() {
        h = (h) ? $(h, e) : e;
        h.bind('mousedown', {
            e: e,
            k: k
        },
        function(v) {
            var d = v.data,
            p = {};
            E = d.e;
            // attempt utilization of dimensions plugin to fix IE issues
            if (E.css('position') != 'relative') {
                try {
                    E.position(p);
                } catch(e) {}
            }
            M = {
                X: p.left || f('left') || 0,
                Y: p.top || f('top') || 0,
                W: f('width') || E[0].scrollWidth || 0,
                H: f('height') || E[0].scrollHeight || 0,
                pX: v.pageX,
                pY: v.pageY,
                k: d.k,
                o: E.css('opacity')
            };
            E.css({opacity: 0.8});
            $(document).mousemove($.jqDnR.drag).mouseup($.jqDnR.stop);
            return (false);
        });
    });
},
f = function(k) {
    return parseInt(E.css(k)) || false;
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's interested, the solution I found was to store the settings in jQuery's .data(). This worked like a charm for me.
     $(this).data({'ratio': settings.keepRatio, 'minx': settings.minx});